# LeetCode: Trapping Rain Water DP C#

Tags: c#, performance, programming-challenge, dynamic-programming

Please review for performance and C# style.

I already solved this question in 1 way.
[LeetCode: trapping rain water C#](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/222077/leetcode-trapping-rain-water-c)

I tried also the dynamic programming approch

https://leetcode.com/problems/trapping-rain-water/

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace ArrayQuestions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// https://leetcode.com/problems/trapping-rain-water/
    /// </summary>
    [TestClass]
    public class TrappingRainWater
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            int[] height = { 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1 };
            Assert.AreEqual(6, TrapDynamicProgramming(height));
        }

        public int TrapDynamicProgramming(int[] height)
        {
            if (height == null || height.Length == 0)
            {
                return 0;
            }

            int ans = 0;
            int size = height.Length;
            var leftMax = Enumerable.Repeat(0, size).ToList();
            var rightMax = Enumerable.Repeat(0, size).ToList();

            //compute the max height from the left for each cell
            //starting from the left
            leftMax[0] = height[0];
            for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
            {
                leftMax[i] = Math.Max(height[i], leftMax[i - 1]);
            }

            //compute the max height from the right for each cell
            //starting from the right..
            rightMax[size - 1] = height[size - 1];
            for (int i = size - 2; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                rightMax[i] = Math.Max(height[i], rightMax[i + 1]);
            }

            //the amount of water is the minimal between left and right height.
            // and we need to remove the height of the cell, think of this
            // like where the ground starts
            for (int i = 1; i < size - 1; i++)
            {
                ans += Math.Min(leftMax[i], rightMax[i]) - height[i];
            }

            return ans;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason to use lists instead of arrays, `new int[size]` will give you an array full of `0`s without any overhead.

You can get away with creating only one array (`leftMax`) and then while computing the values of `rightMax`, instead of saving them into an array, complete the full calculation of how much to add to `ans`. Like this:

```
public int TrapDynamicProgramming(int[] height)
{
    if (height == null || height.Length == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    int ans = 0;
    int size = height.Length;
    int[] leftMax = new int[size];

    leftMax[0] = height[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        leftMax[i] = Math.Max(height[i], leftMax[i - 1]);
    }

    int rightMax = height[size - 1];
    for (int i = size - 2; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        rightMax = Math.Max(height[i], rightMax);
        ans += Math.Min(leftMax[i], rightMax) - height[i];
    }

    return ans;
}
```